# Is there a way of adding a footnote to a gtsummary table that will persist after merging with another table?

Tags: gtsummary, footnotes

I have two tables 'tbl' that I have merged. I want to add a footnote to the final merged table, but it doesn't work for me.
I've tried both adding it to the individual tables like so:

```
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")

tbl <- 
  glm(response ~ grade, trial, family = binomial) %>% 
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  add_glance_table(include = nobs) %>%
  add_n(location = c("label", "level")) %>%
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ "models")
```

And it works for the individual tables, but as soon as I merge them the footnote disappears.

I've tried adding it to the merged table like so, but without success:

```
tbl_final <- 
  tbl_merge(list(tbl, tbl), tab_spanner = c("**Men**", "**Women**")) %>%
modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ "Models")
```

How should I go about it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `all_stat_cols()`, which is intended for use with `tbl_summary()` objects, rather than `tbl_regression()` tables. Use the `show_header_names()` function to print the column names to be able to place the footnotes on the columns you need, e.g. `modify_footnote(estimate ~ "Odds Ratio")`

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks a lot! Another question then adding to that. Is there a way of adding the footnote to one of the table spanners. In order to footnote all the columns for one of the models. For example to the model named "Women". Instead of just one of the individual columns like 'estimate'?

Comment: You can add footnotes to spanning headers by converting the gtsummary table to gt with as_gt(). Then you can use the gt package's functions to place the footnote in the spanner